# Git sqash and rebase workflow, with a staging and master branch

Tags: git, merge, version-control, rebase, squash

There are a lot of questions regarding "Git Workflow and Rebase" on SO, however I wasn't able to find one addressing this problem: We work with a `master` branch, which gets deployed to production but also `staging` branch, which gets deployed to a test server.

Most tutorials ex. [this one](https://blog.carbonfive.com/2017/08/28/always-squash-and-rebase-your-git-commits/), explain to create a feature branch, if there are multiple commits, to squash them and then rebase on top of `master` and finally merge that branch into `master`.

This would look something like the following:

```
git checkout -b featureX # create feature branch

# do work on feature branch
git add .
git commit -m "commit 1"
git add .
git commit -m "commit 2"

git rebase -i HEAD~2 # squash into 1 commit
git checkout master 
git pull origin master # update master
git checkout featureX
git rebase master # rebase onto master
git push origin featureX
git checkout master
git merge featureX # merge feature
git push origin master
```

How would that workflow look like, if we first wanted to merge our feature branch into `staging`, test stuff there and only if it works fine, merge it into `master`?
Would we first have to rebase on top of `staging`, merge into it, test it, next rebase on top of master and then merge it? If so, would that mean we should periodically delete `staging` and branch it off `master` again, to keep a clean `staging` branch? What happens if we've already merged something into `staging`, find out something doesn't work and need to make changes in our feature branch? We would squash that branch again but now `staging` has the old version of the feature branch already merged in, would we in that case need to delete `staging` and branch it of master again? What if there wasn't only one feature branch merged into it, but two?

Comment: This is how I would do it:  Feature branches would be branched from staging. When ready, rebase feature onto staging and then merge feature into staging, If there are issues with the feature, branch feature again and commit fixes to the feature.  Then rebase and merge feature into stage again. If it is decided that feature needs to be removed, then you would revert the feature merge commit(s). As staging is a published branch used by multiple people, DO NOT REBASE staging. When ready, you would merge staging into master.

Comment: @DavidSugar So let's assume we've branched `featureX` from `staging`, squased `featureX` and rebased it on to `staging`, merged it into staging. If we have to change again something about `featureX` you'd remove the `featureX` branch and create a new one? Or would you keep `featureX`, add commits to it, squash and rebase it again and merge it again into `staging?

Comment: You would delete the featureX branch when you merged it. (This still keeps the commits. Deleting the branch only deletes the pointer.) Then you could create a new featureX branch from staging at the point when you decide more work is needed on featureX.

Comment: But wouldn't that still have the issue, that in the end we'll end up with two commits, which could be a problem if using `git bisect` as we might have inconsistent state, don't we?

Comment: We will have 2 (or more) commits for `featureX`.  This is not a problem. The first commit was found deficient and we needed to make additional commits to implement `featureX`. We do not want to rebase `staging` as it is in use by others, and we would not want to hide the fact that we implemented `featureX` in two or more parts. `git bisect` will help us locate problems--if a bug is found after the second  `featureX` commit, but the bug is not seen after only the first one, that can help us find the source of the bug.  There is no inconsistent state from having two or more `featureX` commits.